# Cannot get correct result when using MongoDB aggregation in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB aggregation in meteor.

The items in database look like this:

// item1

```
{
  products: {
    aaa: 100,
    bbb: 200
  }
}
```

// item2

```
{
  products: {
    aaa: 300,
    bbb: 400
  }
}
```

My pipeline looks like this

```
 let pipeline = [{
    $limit: 10
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        // …
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$products.aaa"
      }
    }
  }];
```

And it is working perfect. But when I change my database structure to this

// item1

```
{
  products: [
    {code: "aaa", num: 100},
    {code: "bbb", num: 200}
  ]
}
```

// item2

```
{
  products: [
    {code: "aaa", num: 300},
    {code: "bbb", num: 400}
  ]
}
```

The results I got for `total` is always 0, I think my pipeline is wrong. Please see the comment inside:

```
 let pipeline = [{
    $limit: 10
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        // …
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$products.0.num"  // Neither this nor "$products[0].num" works
      }
    }
  }];
```

So how can I write it correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoDB 3.2 ( which won't be the bundled server with meteor, but there is noting stopping you using a seperate server instance. And actually would be recommended ) you can use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/):

```js
let pipeline = [
    { "$limit": 10 }, 
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        // …
      },
      "total": {
        "$sum": { "$arrayElemAt": [
            { "$map": {
                "input": "$products",
                "as": "product",
                "in": "$$product.num"
            }},
            0
        ]}
      }
    }}
];
```

With older versions, use "two" [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages and the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator after processing with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). And that's just for the "first" index value:

```js
let pipeline = [
    { "$limit": 10 },
    { "$unwind": "$products" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",       // The document _id
        "otherField": { "$first": "$eachOtherFieldForGroupingId" },
        "productNum": { "$first": "$products.num" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        // …
      },
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$productNum"
      }
    }}
];
```

So in the latter case, after you `$unwind` you just want to use `$first` to get the "first" index from the array, and it would also be used to get every field you want to use as part of the grouping key from the original document. All elements would be copied for each array member after `$unwind`.

In the former case, `$map` just extracts the `"num"` values for each array member, then `$arrayElemAt` just retrieves the wanted index position.

Naturally the newer method for MongoDB 3.2 is better. If you wanted another array index then you would need to repeatedly get the `$first` element from the array and keep filtering it out from the array results until you reached the required index.

So whilst it's possible in earlier versions, it's a lot of work to get there.

Comment: My meteor is using mongo 2.6.7. So I use the second way. At first I didn't understand the role of `$eachOtherFieldForGroupingId`, but now I got it! Thanks, works perfect!

Comment: @HongboMiao Sorry if that was an abstract term, but there was also the statement *"...and it would also be used to get every field you want to use as part of the grouping key from the original document."* Put in there to clarify. The most common aggregation pipeline mistake is people missing the concept that if you want to reference a field in a later stage after a `$project` or `$group`, then only the fields you actually ask that first usage to "emit" are actually going to be available.

Comment: @HongboMiao For future reference, you get a clearer example if you actually include a sample document and the **full** expression of your code rather than `"_id": { ... }` which is ambiguous and does not actually show the fields referenced. Also stated the "fact", *"...which won't be the bundled server with meteor, but there is noting stopping you using a seperate server instance"*, which whilst might be "simple" to just start up the bundled server with `meteor` within your project in development, real world deployments are going to use an external server. So you should get used to that.